# Duplicate class error caused by 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose' implementation

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, android-lifecycle

### Error -

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

#### Implementation line -

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:$lifecycle_version"
```

I am following a tutorial about jetpack compose and, the next step of the tutorial was to add this library. The library isn't being used yet. So, the app builds fine when it isn't included. But, adding this causes the duplicate class error. It doesn't however cause any issues while building the Gradle. From what I have researched so far, it seems that the issue is that this library contains some other library that has already been added separately and, I cannot identify the library. Also, I tried changing library versions for this to match other lifecycle libraries(older versions). I'll just drop below the Gradle file and the file that stores all the implementations.

look for the comment

```
//--------------was supposed to add this
```

#### Build.gradle -

```
import com.example.crane.buildsrc.Libs

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

// Reads the Google maps key that is used in the AndroidManifest
Properties properties = new Properties()
if (rootProject.file("local.properties").exists()) {
    properties.load(rootProject.file("local.properties").newDataInputStream())
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "androidx.compose.samples.crane"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.compose.samples.crane.CustomTestRunner"

        manifestPlaceholders = [googleMapsKey: properties.getProperty("google.maps.key", "")]
    }

    signingConfigs {
        // We use a bundled debug keystore, to allow debug builds from CI to be upgradable
        debug {
            storeFile rootProject.file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true

        // Disable unused AGP features
        buildConfig false
        aidl false
        renderScript false
        resValues false
        shaders false
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion Libs.AndroidX.Compose.compilerVersion
    }

    packagingOptions {
        // Multiple dependency bring these files in. Exclude them to enable
        // our test APK to build (has no effect on our AARs)
        excludes += "/META-INF/AL2.0"
        excludes += "/META-INF/LGPL2.1"
    }
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version="2.6.0"

    implementation Libs.Kotlin.stdlib
    implementation Libs.Kotlin.Coroutines.android
    implementation Libs.GoogleMaps.maps
    implementation Libs.GoogleMaps.mapsKtx
    constraints {
        // Volley is a transitive dependency of maps
        implementation(Libs.Volley.volley) {
            because("Only volley 1.2.0 or newer are available on maven.google.com")
        }
    }

    implementation Libs.Accompanist.insets
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Activity.activityCompose
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.appcompat
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Compose.runtime
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Compose.foundation
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Compose.material
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Compose.layout
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Compose.animation
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Compose.toolingPreview

    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Lifecycle.viewModelCompose
    implementation Libs.AndroidX.Lifecycle.viewModelKtx
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:$lifecycle_version"//--------------was supposed to add this

    implementation Libs.Hilt.android
    debugImplementation Libs.AndroidX.Compose.tooling
    kapt Libs.Hilt.compiler

    implementation Libs.Coil.coilCompose

    debugImplementation Libs.AndroidX.Compose.uiTestManifest

    androidTestImplementation Libs.JUnit.junit
    androidTestImplementation Libs.AndroidX.Test.core
    androidTestImplementation Libs.AndroidX.Test.runner
    androidTestImplementation Libs.AndroidX.Test.espressoCore
    androidTestImplementation Libs.AndroidX.Test.rules
    androidTestImplementation Libs.AndroidX.Test.Ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation Libs.Kotlin.Coroutines.test
    androidTestImplementation Libs.AndroidX.Compose.uiTest
    androidTestImplementation Libs.Hilt.android
    androidTestImplementation Libs.Hilt.testing
    kaptAndroidTest Libs.Hilt.compiler
}
```

## Dependencies.kt -

```
package com.example.crane.buildsrc

object Versions {
    const val ktLint = "0.45.2"
}

object Libs {
    const val androidGradlePlugin = "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2"
    const val ktLint = "com.pinterest:ktlint:${Versions.ktLint}"

    object GoogleMaps {
        const val maps = "com.google.android.libraries.maps:maps:3.1.0-beta"
        const val mapsKtx = "com.google.maps.android:maps-v3-ktx:3.4.0"
    }

    object Volley {
        const val volley = "com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0"
    }

    object Accompanist {
        const val version = "0.25.1"
        const val insets = "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-insets:$version"
    }

    object Kotlin {
        private const val version = "1.7.10"
        const val stdlib = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$version"
        const val gradlePlugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$version"
        const val extensions = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$version"

        object Coroutines {
            private const val version = "1.6.3"
            const val android = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$version"
            const val test = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$version"
        }
    }

    object AndroidX {
        object Activity {
            const val activityCompose = "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.0"
        }

        const val appcompat = "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2"

        object Compose {
            const val compilerVersion = "1.3.0"
            const val snapshot = ""
            const val version = "1.2.1"

            const val runtime = "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$version"
            const val material = "androidx.compose.material:material:$version"
            const val foundation = "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$version"
            const val layout = "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:$version"
            const val tooling = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$version"
            const val toolingPreview = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$version"
            const val animation = "androidx.compose.animation:animation:$version"
            const val uiTest = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$version"
            const val uiTestManifest = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$version"
        }

        object Lifecycle {
            private const val version = "2.5.0"
            const val viewModelCompose = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$version"
            const val viewModelKtx = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$version"
        }

        object Test {
            private const val version = "1.4.0"
            const val core = "androidx.test:core:$version"
            const val runner = "androidx.test:runner:$version"
            const val rules = "androidx.test:rules:$version"
            object Ext {
                private const val version = "1.1.2"
                const val junit = "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:$version"
            }
            const val espressoCore = "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0"
        }
    }

    object Hilt {
        private const val version = "2.43"

        const val gradlePlugin = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$version"
        const val android = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$version"
        const val compiler = "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$version"
        const val testing = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$version"
    }

    object JUnit {
        private const val version = "4.13"
        const val junit = "junit:junit:$version"
    }

    object Coil {
        const val coilCompose = "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.1.0"
    }
}

object Urls {
    const val mavenCentralSnapshotRepo = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    const val composeSnapshotRepo = "https://androidx.dev/snapshots/builds/" +
            "${Libs.AndroidX.Compose.snapshot}/artifacts/repository/"
}
```

### Note -

Hi there, The project that I am working on is a part of the [android compose training course](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fjetpack-compose-for-android-developers-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects#3). So, it isn't my project and I don't exactly know why the library implementations are added the way they are. They created a separate file which stores all the dependencies as objects and call them inside build.gradle. (look at how dependencies are added)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this library version uses `kotlin-stdlib` 1.8.10.

```
androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:$lifecycle_version
```

And in your dependencies your app is using `kotlin-stdlib` 1.7.10.

```
 object Kotlin {
        private const val version = "1.7.10"
        const val stdlib = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$version"
```

Change the 1.7.10 to 1.8.10 in the dependencies and make sure that build.gradle for **project** has the same version.

Another solution would be to downgrade the version of `lifecycle-runtime-compose` that uses kotlin-stdlib 1.7.10.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, update Kotlin version to the latest along with Compose Compile version and hilt version. The values are given below -

- Kotlin version = "1.8.10"
- Compose compiler version = "1.4.3"
- Hilt version = "2.44"

I think the issue was more about incompatible library versions. So, updating all to the latest seemingly fixed the issue.