# Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10)

Tags: android, android-studio

How to reproduce:

1. Install latest official android studio
2. Create new project from template navigation drawer
3. Choose java
4. Run

Can google android dev fix it?

Comment: I have encountered similar issue and at that time, it was caused by gradle not being updated. Some libraries used later versions of Kotlin hence it caused problems. maybe look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75809841/duplicate-class-error-caused-by-androidx-lifecyclelifecycle-runtime-compose-i) question.  It might give you a rough idea

Comment: yeah, but I'm using java. I don't get why I ave kotlin error using new project -> drawer activity )